# Google weather library

Tags: google-maps-api-3, weather

I'm using Google library time showing it on the map.

The problem I have is that the first window that displays is very small and you have to scroll.
How do I control the size of this window?

Second, I would like to only show the map for the coordinates that I give, and show me the least time around I want.  How do I do that?

This is my code in [here](http://www.alarmaseguridad.com/):

```
         function generartiempo(36.745,-3.87665,'mapatiempo') {
            var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 11,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng,true),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapatiempo'),
            mapOptions);

        var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
          temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.CELSIUS,
          windSpeedUnit: google.maps.weather.WindSpeedUnit.KILOMETERS_PER_HOUR
        });


        weatherLayer.setMap(weatherLayer.getMap() ? null : map);

        var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
        cloudLayer.setMap(map);

    }
<div id="mapatiempo"></div>
#mapatiempo {
width: 268px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #AAAAA8;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Can anyone help?
edit example:http://jsfiddle.net/webyseo/YW2K7/12/
solution?
thanks!!!!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using Google library time showing it on the map", do you mean the weather-forecast?

Comment: Are you asking how to change the size of the map that is displayed?

Comment: if I'm using this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers# WeatherLayer

Comment: No, change the window size of information, not the map.
When you click your eg you open a window and looks to scroll

Comment: update http://jsfiddle.net/webyseo/YW2K7/12/ Hepl me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to define the size of the default infoWindow. Furthermore the size of an infoWindow  is restricted by the size of the map, it can't be larger, so you need to enlarge the map.

What you can do: override the default infoWindow with a custom infoWindow and define the content on your own, so that it fit's into a smaller infoWindow

---

Sample code for a custom infoWindow:(assuming a variable containing the `google.maps.Map`)

```
    //create the weatherLayer
    var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
      temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT,
      clickable:true,
      suppressInfoWindows:true
    });

    //create InfoWondow-instance
    var weatherWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //observe click-event
    google.maps.event.addListener(weatherLayer,'click',function(e){

      //hide infoindow
      weatherWindow.close();

      var content  = document.createElement('ul'),
          weather  = e.featureDetails.forecast,
          unit     = '°'+e.featureDetails.temperatureUnit.toUpperCase();

        //merge current weather and forecast
        weather.push(e.featureDetails.current);

        //create some content(here a short summary)
        for(var i = 0; i<weather.length; ++i){
          var item = content.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
                      .appendChild(document.createTextNode(''))
              w    = weather[i];
              item.data='['+w.shortDay+']'+w.description+
                        '('+w.low+unit+'/'+w.high+unit+')';


        }
        //set content and position of the infoWindow
        weatherWindow.setOptions({position:e.latLng,content:content});
        //...and open the infowindow
         weatherWindow.open(map);
    });
    weatherLayer.setMap(map);
```

---

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pnAyD/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/pnAyD/)

Comment: Thank you very much is what I feared.
You know how I could get the image eg: the sun and overwrite the default window info

Comment: The sun/clouds/whatever on the map are not images, the are a part of a tile, so you can't get them as a single image(but you can click them and the API will respond on the click). To get custom infoWindows set the `suppressInfoWindows`-option of the weatherlayer to `true` and observe the click-event of the weatherLayer. When a click occurs, the passed argument to the click-callback contains the weather-features for the location, you may use them to create the content for an infoWindow as defined inside the documentation.

Comment: Thanks again for real, I just do not understand how to get that part of the mosaic. Can you give me an example if it's not too much to ask. thanks!!!

Comment: oh my god, i love you. thank you very much.
I owe you one.
A hug.