# Selecting what elements from an RSS feed appear in infobox on map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a GeoRSS feed from a Flickr set showing on a map as a KML layer and the images appear as intended in the infoboxes.

Above the image is the text 'Flickr username posted an image', which is the text from the content element of the feed item.

I would like to remove this and I'm trying to find a simple way of only showing the elements from the feed that I want in the infoboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You must supress the default infoWindows and create your own.

How it works I described a couple of hours ago [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727002/google-weather-library/14733063#comment20624301_14733063) (the question there is about a weatherLayer, but the workflow is exactly the same).

The contents of the cklicked item are stored in the featureData-property of the [KMLMouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#KmlMouseEvent)-object, passed as argument to the click-callback. You must parse these  data and create the desired content for the infoWindow.